# Uploading mbtile to PostgreSQL via ogr2ogr results in tile boundaries

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, mbtiles

I have a large .mbtile file (all census tracts in the United States) that I would like to store in PostgreSQL. I am using ogr2ogr to upload the file to a table with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL -lco OVERWRITE=YES "PG:host=${host} dbname=${dbname} user=${user} password=${password}" -nln ${table.name} -nlt geometry
```

When I view the tables from the above command, I see the tile outlines in QGIS. Any suggestions on how to get rid of the tile borders stored in the table?

[image: census tracts in the united states with a grid]

Comment: You can try an st_union on the geometry, or a MINOR buffer